# Embedly Cards don't work in an Angular application

Tags: angularjs, embedly

I want to use Embedly Cards in my web app. It uses Bootstrap and AngularJS. But integrating the cards using the platform.js tool described [here](http://embed.ly/docs/products/cards) doesn't work properly.

The card doesn't get rendered because at the time the integration kicks in the link bound via angular didn't happen  yet.

Are there any hints or tutorials out there that demonstrate how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why it doesn't work. You shouldn't use `embedly-card` as a class for the target anchor tag. As soon as I removed that class or renamed it, the call to `embedly()` was successful.

So, this doesn't work:

```
<a href="{{url}}" class="embedly-card"></a>

embedly('card', '.embedly-card');
```

This works:

```
<a href="{{url}}" class="embedly-cardx"></a>

embedly('card', '.embedly-cardx');
```